Ubuntu Shell Capture using Go
I want to make a automatic shell script.
and capture whole things of shell like input, output and error just like any terminal.
this script is for remote server(ubuntu).
I have tried my ways to do it but not working as I expected.
I am able to do anything but can't handle one condition that is If execute command with 'sudo' so asking for the password in terminal I am able to provide the password via terminal but I want to provide hardcoded password whenever will ask for the password. I can do this also using 'stdinpipe' but this thing pass the password every time. so I want to pass password according to output if ask for password only then pass otherwise not.
for example-

sudo 'command'
Enter password: password (I am unable to put condition here if this line comes then pass the password)
sudo 'command'
here no nedd to pass password

        fmt.Println("Started")
        // Define SSH connection parameters
        host := "host_name"
        port := "port"
        user := "user"
        password := "password"

        // Establish SSH connection
        client, err := connectToSSH(host, port, user, password)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to SSH server: %v", err)
        }
        defer client.Close()

        session, err := client.NewSession()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to get New Session: %v", err)
        }
        defer session.Close()

        // Set up standard input/output/error
        stdin, err := session.StdinPipe()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to create stdin pipe: %v", err)
        }

        stdout, err := session.StdoutPipe()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to create stdout pipe: %v", err)
        }

        stderr, err := session.StderrPipe()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to create stderr pipe: %v", err)
        }

        defer stdin.Close()

        outSC := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
        errSC := bufio.NewScanner(stderr)

        // Start goroutine to handle output
        err = session.Shell()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to SSH Shell: %v", err)
        }
        runCommand(stdin, "pwd")
        runCommand(stdin, "sudo su")
        runCommand(stdin, "pwd")

        for outSC.Scan() || errSC.Scan() {
            fmt.Println(outSC.Text())
            fmt.Println(errSC.Text())
            if strings.Contains(outSC.Text(), "sudo") && strings.Contains(outSC.Text(), "password") {
                runCommand(stdin, "password")
            }
        }
        // runCommand(stdin, "pwd")

        // runCommand(stdin, "cd new_folde1r")

        // runCommand(stdin, "pwd")

        // Wait for the session to finish
        err = session.Wait()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Session returned error: %v", err)
        }

}

func connectToSSH(host, port, user, password string) (*ssh.Client, error) {
    // Create SSH client config with password
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: user,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password(password),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(), // Insecure; use known_hosts in production
        BannerCallback:  ssh.BannerDisplayStderr(),
    }

    // Connect to SSH server
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", host+":"+port, config)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return client, nil
}

func runCommand(stdin io.WriteCloser, cmd string) error {

    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println(cmd)
    _, err := stdin.Write([]byte(cmd + "\n")) // Add a newline character
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to write to stdin:", err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}



sudo reads a password directly from the terminal for security. You can use -S (see man sudo), but it's much better to authorize this in a different manner without using plain text passwords

[1/2] I think your problem stems from the fact tools like sudo expect interactive communications with them: basically, what use it for sudo if you could just pipe a file containing the credentials to it? Everyone would just do that, resulting in zero security (if you think of it a bit more, you'll notice that GUI desktop environments go even farther–presenting the user with "system-modal" dialogs when security is involved). In your simple session setup the commands run in a way their standard input stream is not connected to something looking like an interactive teminal, and sudo…

[2/2] …does not work. Still, there's a way out called "pseudo-terminals"; you can start here. Basically, you make sudo run on a PTY and then interact with it: read what it writes, and if it writes the phrase you expect, you send the password to it; otherwise you do not.

Sounds like you need expect, not go.

@JimB I have used this command 'sudo -S adduser $username --gecos '' --disabled-password' as well, there are two to pass password-

pass from terminal
pass using stdin
here is a one problem if I pass from terminal so script is not fully automated. if pass in stdin so there are again two condition-
if ask for password then fine.
already session have password then terminal run that as a command so if someone have password like that 'rm -rf/' that mean terminal not consider password. terminal execute this as a command so this is big issue.


@kostix can you please give me some example code with condition?

For example, this from there, and also please work yourself through the results of this search query.

BTW, if you'd like to follow the path of least resistance, and can configure the target host, you can install the venerable sshpass there and have it take care of the "interactive" part for you.

@kostix thanks, this is working but not working with 'sudo su' command. If I execute 'sudo su' command then it's stuck. does not executes any command even not exited. I have to manually close the program.

What does it print when invoked this way? (While we're at it, sudo su is almost always wrong these days: you need sudo su - so that su gives you expected environment such as having /sbin and /usr/sbin in the PATH.)
